# Celery important slowdown on subprocess

Tags: python, celery

In the context of a web app, I recently switched some time consuming processing (latex rendering) from my "main program" to celery.

And while it worked perfectly fine on my laptop during dev, on my production server the time needed to do this processing have more than tripled.

I narrowed down the problem to the core processing in itself, and I've profiled it, but I'm completely lost on what could cause such a difference.

**Core processing**

```
def process(content, passes=2):
    tmp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()

    with open(os.path.join(tmp_dir, 'content.tex'), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(content.encode('utf-8'))

    pr = cProfile.Profile()
    pr.enable()

    for _ in range(passes):
        process = subprocess32.Popen(
            [
                '/path/to/lualatex',
                '--interaction',
                'nonstopmode',
                '--output-directory',
                tmp_dir,
                '--jobname',
                'output',
                'content.tex',
            ],
            cwd=tmp_dir,
            stdout=FNULL,
            stderr=FNULL,
            bufsize=0,
        )

        process.wait()

        if process.returncode != 0:
            with open(os.path.join(tmp_dir, 'output.log'), 'rb') as f:
                raise LatexError(f.read())

    pr.disable()
    pr.dump_stats('/path/to/profile')

    with open(os.path.join(tmp_dir, 'output.pdf'), 'rb') as pdf:
        pdf_bytes = pdf.read()

    shutil.rmtree(tmp_dir)
    return pdf_bytes
```

**Profile "outside" celery**

```
80 function calls in 1.973 seconds

Ordered by: internal time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    2    1.969    0.985    1.969    0.985 {posix.waitpid}
    2    0.002    0.001    0.002    0.001 {_posixsubprocess.fork_exec}
    2    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {posix.read}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.002 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:1323(_execute_child)
    2    0.000    0.000    1.969    0.985 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:1644(wait)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.002 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:713(__init__)
    4    0.000    0.000    1.970    0.493 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:540(_eintr_retry_call)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:1578(_handle_exitstatus)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py:127(dirname)
    2    0.000    0.000    1.969    0.985 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:1629(_try_wait)
    4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.close}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_posixsubprocess.cloexec_pipe}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:872(__del__)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:1245(_get_handles)
   10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {isinstance}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {sorted}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:525(_cleanup)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.WIFSIGNALED}
    3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'release' of 'thread.lock' objects}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'rfind' of 'str' objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {getattr}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {thread.allocate_lock}
    4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'fileno' of 'file' objects}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:1355(fs_encode)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'rstrip' of 'str' objects}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'acquire' of 'thread.lock' objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:1593(_internal_poll)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.WEXITSTATUS}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {sys.getfilesystemencoding}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.WIFEXITED}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
```

**Profile with celery**

```
80 function calls in 6.260 seconds

Ordered by: internal time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    2    6.256    3.128    6.256    3.128 {posix.waitpid}
    2    0.002    0.001    0.002    0.001 {_posixsubprocess.fork_exec}
    2    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {posix.read}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.002 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:1323(_execute_child)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.002 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:713(__init__)
    2    0.000    0.000    6.256    3.128 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:1644(wait)
    4    0.000    0.000    6.258    1.564 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:540(_eintr_retry_call)
    4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.close}
    2    0.000    0.000    6.256    3.128 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:1629(_try_wait)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:1578(_handle_exitstatus)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py:127(dirname)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_posixsubprocess.cloexec_pipe}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:1245(_get_handles)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:872(__del__)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {sorted}
   10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {isinstance}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.WIFSIGNALED}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:525(_cleanup)
    3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:1355(fs_encode)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'release' of 'thread.lock' objects}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'rfind' of 'str' objects}
    4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'fileno' of 'file' objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {getattr}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {thread.allocate_lock}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'acquire' of 'thread.lock' objects}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'rstrip' of 'str' objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /home/admin/.envs/sydpnl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:1593(_internal_poll)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.WEXITSTATUS}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.WIFEXITED}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {sys.getfilesystemencoding}
```

**Side facts**

I'm running Debian 7.8 and Python 2.7.3 on my server.

**EDIT 01/4/2015**

Changed code and profile a small bit to highlight where (I think) the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering (and closing) this question to avoid https://xkcd.com/979/.

It seems that the problem was coming from the process manager (circus) I used to manage the celery process. Circus was probably reducing the process resources somehow.

Switching to another process manager resolved the issue.